# ggplot2 column chart with facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a R `ggplot2` chart with columns grouping one variable, and a `facet_grid` to break down by another. Both ways I've tried have failed:

1) Setting `x` as the `facet_grid` variable breaks down by that variable twice:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=price, fill=color)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    facet_grid(cut ~ ., scales="free")
```

[image]

2) Dropping `x` produces an error:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=price, fill=color)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    facet_grid(cut ~ ., scales="free")
# Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode): 
# argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `x` to the same variable as the `color` arg:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=color, y=price, fill=color)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    facet_grid(cut ~ ., scales="free")
```

[image]

Comment: These price values seem to be inaccurate. For instance the mean price of diamonds that are Fair and of color D is $4291, and the plot shows a value 3x as high.                                                                           
  diamonds %>% 
  filter(cut == "Fair", color == "D") %>% 
  summarise(price = mean(price, na.rm = TRUE))